# Ideal class group of $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{-29}]$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

What is the ideal class group of $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{-29}]$? I think it could be the cyclic group of order 4 or order 6, but am not sure.

Comment: [This page](http://www.numbertheory.org/classnos/) says that has order $6$. (The discriminant is -116.)

Comment: And Table 5 on p. 322 of Alaca & Williams gives $\{1, A, A^2, A^3, A^4, A^5\} \simeq \mathbb Z_6$, with $A = [\langle 3, 1 + \sqrt{-29} \rangle]$.

Comment: Just a little note: turns out `mathbb` can inhibit the proper subtraction sign. Compare `\mathbb{Q[\sqrt{-29}]}` -> $\mathbb{Q[\sqrt{-29}]}$ to `\mathbb Q[\sqrt{-29}]` -> $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{-29}]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [sage maths](https://cloud.sagemath.com/projects/97ce992e-ba7e-4176-8c00-4cb08a48b48f/files/class%20group%20-%20extension%20of%20degree%203.sagews) its class group is $C_6$ with generator $(3, a + 2)$ where $a = \sqrt{-29}$

$$\mathfrak{C} = \{(1),(3, a + 2),(5, a + 4),(2, a + 1),(5, a + 1),(3, a + 1)\}$$